# How do you convert Geometry in WKT to GeoJSON?

Tags: scala, geometry, geojson, wkt

I'm looking for a package / library in Scala where you can convert Geometry in WKT to GeoJSON.

Thanks alot

Comment: Maybe Topology Suite https://github.com/locationtech/jts or https://www.geotools.org/

Comment: Hi gaston, thanks alot let me try